# My wordpress page seems to be loading jQuery Migrate and jQuery 1.10.2, what's the difference?

Tags: jquery

I'm just going through some site performance check lists and noticed that my wordpress site is loading both jQuery-migrate and jQuery 1.10.2.

Do I need them both and what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [docs for the Migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) state:

> The uncompressed development version of the jQuery Migrate plugin
> includes console log output to warn when specific deprecated and/or
> removed features are being used. This makes it valuable as a migration
> debugging tool for finding and remediating issues in existing jQuery
> code and plugins. It can be used for its diagnostics with versions of
> jQuery core all the way back to 1.6.4.
>
> The compressed version of the plugin does not generate any log output,
> and can be used on production sites when jQuery 1.9 or higher is
> desired but older incompatible jQuery code or plugins must also be
> used. Ideally this would only be used as a short-term solution, but
> that's a decision for you to make.

See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

So one file is actually jQuery, and the other is a plugin used for debugging.